# How does the Intel's xHC address USB devices and how to know if the device is USB2 or USB3?

Tags: x86, usb, osdev

I've read parts of the xHCI specification here: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/extensible-host-controler-interface-usb-xhci.pdf. The specification is quite overwhelming because, when you read a section, it refers to another which refers to another and it becomes quite overwhelming. It is definitely not simple. I've read mostly chapters 3, 4, 5 and 6. By reading these chapters I could get a clearer understanding but I'm losing some information here and there and it prevents me from getting a clear understanding of a step by step process to get the xHC up and running.

The main question I have is about the actual general topology of the xHC and how it works with USB. The way I understand it is that the xHC has a root USB hub. It is a normal hub which presents several USB ports to the user. These ports are the actual ports you see on the motherboard. If this is correct, then it would mean that, on most systems, the xHCI would have only one root USB hub which presents a few USB ports to the user. The MaxPorts value in the HCSPARAMS1 is the actual number of these motherboard ports.

Is what I mention above true?

As to what I understand, each device connected to the root USB hub gets a Device Context struct in the Device Context Base Address Array. The Device Context struct has a Slot Context struct which refers to all endpoints and several Endpoint Context structs which refers to one specific endpoint.

What I understand from this is that there is one Device Context struct for each USB device (including USB hubs) and that each USB device (like hubs) can have several enpoints which all get an Endpoint Context struct in the Device Context for this USB device. The endpoint is an actual USB port into which you can plug an actual USB device. This USB device (for example a USB drive or keyboard) will get another Device Context struct which will have only one Slot Context struct but no Endpoint Context struct (because it isn't a hub so it has no endpoint).

Is an Endpoint Context struct representing an actual USB port?

Does an actual USB device (like a USB drive or a keyboard) get a Device Context struct with only one Slot Context struct with no Endpoint Context struct?

Also, does the root USB hub (the one on the xHC) have an actual Device Context struct?

From all this, I think I need to be able to tell if a device is USB2 or USB3 because there seems to be differences as to how one should interact with each of these types of devices. How does one tell if a device is USB2 or USB3?

Comment: "The MaxPorts value in the HCSPARAMS1" is the count of register sets, not actual physical ports, also called sockets.

Comment: As for contexts, I believe you have a misunderstanding of what the term "endpoint" means.  A USB drive, called a Mass Storage Device (MSD) will have a single SLOT allocated to it, but can have many endpoints.  One for the CONTROL ep, one for the IN ep, one for the OUT ep, as well as others depending on the type of MSD.  All devices have at least one endpoint, the CONTROL endpoint.  A hub can have another endpoint, called the INTERRUPT endpoint.

Comment: There will be an Endpoint Context for each endpoint.  Also, if an endpoint has a value of 5, for example, there will be a (possibly unused) endpoint context for each number up to and including 5.  As for determining a USB3 or USB2 device, a socket may have two port register sets.  Depending on which register set becomes active *after* a reset, will tell you which port register set to use, also telling you if the device is USB 3 or USB 2 device.

Comment: I am a fellow hobbyist and the USB has been my main interest for many years.  I have actually written a [book specifically](http://www.fysnet.net/the_universal_serial_bus.htm) about the questions you ask, explaining in a hobbyist's point of view.  The source code to that book is freely available.

Comment: Thank you for the info! Yes I definitely have some misconceptions about the meaning of endpoint. I read further and can tell that there is one endpoint 0 IN/OUT for the Default Control which lets me get info on further endpoints by using a GET_CONFIGURATION request. Also, how to tell if the device is USB3 or 2 depending on which port register set becomes active? I get that USB3 gets 2 register sets because it has 2 sets of pins but how to tell if it is a USB3 or 2 device?

Comment: A USB3 socket *may* have two register ports--and it may not.  You have to parse the "Capabilities" to find which register sets belong to which sockets and *if* a register set has a matching 'other speed' set.  When you 'reset' the USB3 register set, if the device is a USB3 device, it will properly reset and show in the register set. If not, try the 'other speed' paired register set for this socket.

Comment: Should you reset a port? It is nowhere mentionned in the USB initialization process of the xHCI specification for USB3 devices. Which register in the Capabilities tells me which port belongs to which socket. Isn't the capabilities for the MSI-X functionnality?

Comment: The specification says that USB3 ports attempt to automatically move to the enabled state while a USB2 port requires a reset from software. How does one make the difference between a USB3 port and a USB2 port.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, look for the "protocol" ID in the "Capabilities" area.  Most of the time, the first "count" of register sets are USB3 and then are followed by a "count" of USB2 sets.  However, this is not always the case.  It is quite common to have more USB2 sets than USB3.

Comment: @fysnet Ok thank you. Yes I could find this in chapter 7 of the spec. I should look for Revision Major and Revision Minor which tells me if a set of ports is USB3 or USB2. The capability has the ID 0x2 which is the Supported Protocol type.